# SQL: how to produce table of all the individual ID's that had more than 2 occurrences within 24 hours of each other

Tags: mysql, sql, zoho

I have a table as shown below

| User ID | Payment ID | DateTime | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UID1 | 12dw4r434t | 19/08/2020 13:40:12 | 10 |
| UID2 | k2dw86774z | 19/08/2020 14:30:52 | 5 |
| UID3 | 5hjs982835 | 17/08/2020 09:56:08 | 7 |
| UID1 | hg19283jdg | 20/08/2020 07:59:33 | 12 |
| UID1 | 2563ghmn77 | 20/08/2020 08:10:22 | 54 |
| UID2 | 999gegh77d | 19/08/2020 17:11:37 | 67 |
| UID2 | mnnnhsgdje | 20/08/2020 19:18:55 | 67 |
| UID1 | qccc356njd | 20/08/2020 16:10:11 | 87 |
| UID3 | mmk0999111 | 18/08/2020 05:16:29 | 4 |
| UID3 | yyy63hgd72 | 18/08/2020 05:25:44 | 4 |

I want to be able to produce a table/list of all the User IDs that have at least 3 (more than 2) occurrences within 24 hours of each other.

The result for the above data would be:

| User ID |
| --- |
| UID1 |
| UID3 |

To be clear, I want the 24 hour period to be rolling. I am not looking for the results over a fixed date range.

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION OUTPUT**

Another output solution that would satisfy my need would be to produce a table with an extra column (Count) added to the table above. For every row, the Count column counts how many transactions within the whole table are within 24 hours (and for the same User ID)of the transaction for the current row . I have easily managed to do this using COUNTIF in Excel, but cannot get it working in SQL. Below is how I tried to do this:

```
SELECT
         a."User Id",
         a."Payment Id",
         a."created_at",
         a."Amount",
         b.m_count
FROM  "Payment Summary Table" AS  a
INNER JOIN( SELECT
             "User Id",
             "created_at",
             COUNT(*) AS m_count
    FROM  "Payment Summary Table" 
    GROUP BY "Merchant",
          "amount" 
) AS  b ON a."User Id"  = b."User Id"
     AND    b."created_at" <= dateadd (hour, 24, a."created_at")
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the first of the three using `lead()` and date arithmetic:

```
select pst.*
from (select pst.*,
             lead(created_at, 2) over (partition by user_id order by created_at) as created_at_2
      from payment_summary_table pst
     ) pst
where created_at_2 < dateadd(hour, 24, created_at);
```

This looks at the payment 2 rows ahead for the user.  If it is within 24 hours, then the three payments are within 24 hours.

If you just want the users, replace the `select` with:

```
select distinct user_id
```